# MySQL - how do I write this Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to SQL and I wanted some help in writing this SQL query.

I have a movie table like this:

```
Movie_id Actor_name  Director_name
1         a             AA
1         b             AA
2         b             BB
2         d             BB
```

Now I want to print out all the pairs of actors and directors who have not worked with each other - for eg in this case it will print out (a,BB) and (d,AA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT a.Actor_name, d.Director_name
FROM (
  (SELECT DISTINCT Actor_name from movie) a
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT Director_name from movie) d
) WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM movie m
  WHERE m.Actor_name=a.Actor_name
    AND m.Director_name=d.Director_name
)
```

The idea is to produce all possible pairs of actors and directors (the cartesian product join in the middle of the query), then filter its results to exclude pairs connected through a movie (the `NOT EXISTS` condition).

Here is a [demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20b2a/3)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by first developing all pairs of actors and directors with a cross join (i.e. [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)), and then filter this list down using the table of observed relationships.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    -- cross join
    SELECT a.actor_name, d.director_name
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT actor_name FROM movies) a
    ,(SELECT DISTINCT director_name FROM movies) d
    ) pairs
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM movies m
    WHERE pairs.actor_name = m.actor_name
    AND pairs.director_name = m.director_name
    )
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c671b/1/0) (schema basically scavenged from dasblinkenlight's fiddle since he beat me to it).

Answer (score 1):

One alternative:

```
select distinct t1.actor_name, t2.director_name from t t1, t t2
where (t1.actor_name, t2.director_name) not in (
    select actor_name, director_name from t)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcebe/1).

Another alternative:

```
select distinct t1.actor_name, t2.director_name from t t1
cross join t t2 left join t t3
on t1.actor_name = t3.actor_name and t2.director_name = t3.director_name
where t3.actor_name is null
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31655/1).

Comment: Your first one is the simplest one. I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Also based in cartesian product (with some differences with previous responses):

```
select distinct m.Actor_name, mo.Director_name
from movie m
cross join movie mo
where (not exists (select mv.Actor_name, mv.Director_name
                   from movie mv 
                   where (mv.Actor_name = m.Actor_name and mv.Director_name = mo.Director_name)))
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be0c1/23)